# Error executing .sh command using Erlang build

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I get an error like this when I execute the command. How do I fix this error?

- Erlang Version: 22.3
- Operating System: Centos OS 7

[image: Code error picture]

```json
{"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{1,erl_parse,["syntax error before: ","','"]}}},[{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]}}
init terminating in do_boot ({{badmatch,{error,{1,erl_parse,[_]}}},[{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]})
```

Crash dump is being written to: `erl_crash.dump`...done

Comment: can you please share with us the details of do_boot function ?

Comment: My guess is that `dev.sh` passes an `-eval` argument to Erlang, but the `-eval` argument has a syntax error. Could you share the contents of `dev.sh`?

Comment: @legoscia I have shared it below can you help me, to get it working. Thank you.

Comment: @legoscia I have shared it below can you help me, to get it working. Thank you.

Comment: @NalinRanjan I have shared it below can you help me, to get it working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Mot likely the $1 and $option are not resolving to correct values...

As I try the following command, trying to simulate what might be executing as part of the shell script, I get the same error as you are...

```
$ erl -noshell -pa /tools_core/ebin -pa ./ebin -eval "make:all(),gen_data:gen(,)" -s c q
{"init terminating in do_boot",{{badmatch,{error,{1,erl_parse,["syntax error before: ","','"]}}},[{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]}}
init terminating in do_boot ({{badmatch,{error,{1,erl_parse,[_]}}},[{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]})

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
```

So most likely, you should check what values they are resolving to. If they are resolving to an empty value, then erlang parse will fail. Since it says **before ,**, I suspect it's the resolution of $1 which is not happening properly.

can you echo these values and let us know what are they resolving to??

Most likely, $1 should take the command line argument which gets passed along while invoking this shell script. Since its your environment, can't say much. But please try and share what $1 is resolving to in your case.

Answer (score 0):

It is syntax error, not difficult to debug.
You should have source code and check the program and write some debug statement if necessary.

Comment: I have shared it below can you help me, to get it working. Thank you.